# Easyautocomplete + Vue.js - how to update stored variable by click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, easyautocomplete

I have an input text field, which value is stored in "app.adress" component in Vue. I'm now using "Easy-autocomplete" plugin, which displays a list of suggested values. When I click one it appears in the text field, but is not saved in "app.adress" component. For example, I type "uni", I click suggested value "United Kingdom", it appears in the text field, but only "uni" is saved in the "app.adress". Any suggestions how to update Vue component by click?

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is too late. But I just want to share my work around on this issue. Instead of using `v-model` to bind the value of my input, I just add `@change` event listener and call a method that will update my data.

**Edit:** Other solution is to use the event functions of EasyAutocomplete like the `onChooseEvent`.